# Telerik RADGrid and identifying columns

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I'm adding columns to the RADGrid in the following way.

```
grid.Columns.Add(
                new GridViewDataColumn
                    {
                        Name = name,
                        Header = header,
                        DataMemberBinding = new Binding(item),

                    });
```

I tried to set the `Name` property to an `Id` value that use to track them. However, I got an execption saying that `0` -- in my case -- was not a valid value for `Name`. Is there some property I can use to identify the columns later? I thought `Name` could be use in the same way as in Java Swing :P

EDIT: (from comments)

I have an ObservableCollection of dynamic objects that I track and contain all the info coming from DB. In this info coming from DB, there are ColumnID and Column Name. I saw this code(above) in the application to add columns at run time to the RADGrid. It only sets the Column Names. I want to perform some action when the DoubleClick event of the RadGrid occurs. I need to identify what column the user clicked on. Since columns could have the same name, I wonder if there is a way to store the Column Id somewhere in the GridViewDataColumn.

Comment: There is not enough information to adequately answer the question.

Comment: I have an ObservableCollection of dynamic objects that I track and contain all the info coming from DB. In this info coming from DB, there are ColumnID and Column Name. I saw this code(above) in the application to add columns at run time to the RADGrid. It only sets the Column Names. I want to perform some action when the DoubleClick event of the RadGrid occurs. I need to identify what column the user clicked on. Since columns could have the same name, I wonder if there is a way to store the Column Id somewhere in the GridViewDataColumn.

Comment: Add the above to your question.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question specifically:

> Is there some property I can use to identify the columns later?

Your best bet is to save (maybe use a `Dictionary`) and use the column index to be able to find this column again.  You can always do:

```
grid.Columns[index]
```

To access the column and do your work later.